# Vehicle Color Detection accuracy

Tags: opencv, colors

I am doing a vehicle color detection. i have implemented a simple method. Steps are below.

Getting the ROI ( above the license plate on the vehicle bonnet area) (Extracted Image Window)
Getting the HS histogram of ROI
Histogram Back-projection ( BackProj Window)
From the Back-projection area extracting the vehicle image (devide Window)
Calculating distance of HS values from predefined HS values for colors. (Doing this for each and every pixcel on the vehicle area shown in devide Window)
Voting the color and getting the color which has the maximum number of votes.
From thees steps i have only achieved an accuracy of 75%. How can i increase the accuracy? Is there any other method to do this?

I am very new to opencv :) :)
[click this for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU80T.jpg)

[New Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUahz.png)

Comment: you should try to find out the reason for failures. Are there reflections of different colors? Wrong ROI extraction? missing-predefined HS values? Signal noise?

Comment: New picture - http://i.stack.imgur.com/OUahz.png 
As in the new picture you can see that my ROI is right above the license plate. I have the c ordinates of the top left corner  of the license plate so i go up 250 pixels to define the ROI.
As you can see on the image sometime the ROI has a big reflection of the sky.
I have defined 11 colors in HS values.
Please help me on this.